# Pygame installed on windows, getting "pygame.error: Failed loading libwebp-7.dll" when trying to call pygame.image.load()

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, python-3.9

I've got python 3.9.1 running on a windows 10 machine. I have pygame 2.0.1 installed on my machine via pip

(`python -m pip install https://github.com/pygame/pygame/releases/download/2.0.1/pygame-2.0.1-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl`)

however on calling `pygame.image.load("file.png")` I get the error:

`pygame.error: Failed loading libwebp-7.dll: The specified module could not be found.`

I've tried installing through `pip install pygame`
and running the tests in `pygame.tests` but they run fine.

Comment: `pip install pygame` doesnt work for me, read the penultimate sentence.

Comment: the tests run fine, my program still raises `pygame.error: Failed loading libwebp-7.dll: The specified module could not be found.`

Comment: well if it worked for me that would be just great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to fix this error by using the whl file at
[https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pygame](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#pygame)
rather than from the github releases.
I'm not sure why this worked, but I hope anyone else having this issue is helped by this.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue, but I discovered that it was due to the image being too low resolution for the size of window being drawn, swapping the image for a higher resolution version fixed the problem.